# How do I remove my account erroneously associated with my company?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, profile-page

I have added my wrong profile to the company for job search and I want to remove it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can remove a profile from the company page following these steps:

1. Go to your [developer story preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences)
2. On the bottom, there is the "Company pages" section, with a link to "Revoke permission". Click there and that should be it.

I'm adding an image because I couldn't pass on the opportunity to draw circles:
[image: revoke permission]

Comment: It shows your "circle" skills are a bit off ...

Comment: @rene that's exactly why I couldn't pass on the opportunity ;)

Comment: FHC should use a thinner line. Otherwise +1

Comment: `*swirls wine*` I appreciate the non-connecting FHC. Nice touch.

Comment: @MattR The FreeHand Circle is great, but the real design expertise shines in the perfect hat placement on his avatar!

Comment: @NH. <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: +1 for perfect hat placement, it's really worth taking a closer look at your profil picture. Would also +1 for FCH but i'm a normal human... can't double vote.

Comment: ITT freecircle hands

Comment: @AntoinePelletier Indeed. I was almost *almost* able to make that hat work with my avatar, but it just didn't want to look good. Then again, that's true for *most* hats (they just don't include any horn-holes...or really, handle not-forward-facing faces at all)

Comment: @Draco18s, try reimplementing your hat with glCullFace(GL_NONE).

Comment: @visibleman Ha! Thanks for that :)